# DS-160: photo dimensions are not correct. What should I do?

Tags: visas, usa, paperwork, consulates

I have just confirmed my [DS-160](http://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/forms/ds-160--online-nonimmigrant-visa-application.html) (U.S. Online Nonimmigrant Visa Application) and so the electronic visa has just been submitted to the chosen consulate in my home country.

However, I just realised that I the photo I uploaded doesn't meet the dimension requirements that it should have (head is too small in the photo). What should I do? Should I just fill another DS-160 application or contact the consulate or not do anything?

(I have confirmed the DS-160 application but I do not have paid the application fee nor take the appointment in the consulate yet).

Comment: Not doing anything is probably not a good idea, they tend to be picky about their requirements. Have you contacted them yet ?

Comment: I tried but it's hard, it seems it's very difficult to contact the consulate by phone. I will try by email but I fear that delays will be long.

Comment: Seems like making another application is your best bet, more so that you haven't made an appointment or paid anything

Comment: @blackbird57 do you think that they might complain about having applied twice?

Comment: You can then explain you made a mistake and had trouble contacting them by phone. There's probably a way to pull or cancel your other application

Comment: It may still be ok. if the size in pixels is ok. (600 by 600 pixels).

Comment: @CountIblis not sure that's true, they need to print those for the visa so those will translate into wrong dimensions/sizes

Comment: My DS160 says - "Photo will be taken at the ASC". I didn't have to upload any photo for filling DS-160. This might be useful for future applicants.

Answer (score 7):

If the photo is not suitable, than at the time you attend the consulate they will instruct you to provide a physical photo that meets the requirements.  I've seen this occur for multiple people in the Sydney consulate - for each person they directed them to a nearby shop that could take the photo, and would not allow them to proceed with the application until they returned with the photo.

Given that you haven't done anything yet other than submit the DS-160, your options are to either :

- Start the process again and submit a new DS-160, then use this DS-160 number when making your appointment. If you go this path there is no need to cancel/etc your existing DS-160. or
- Stick with the current DS-160, and take 2 copies of a suitable photo with you to the interview. If they decide the photo submitted with the DS-160 is not suitable, then they will be able to use these photos instead.